# Is there any limitation to update only a number of objects using the CrudRepository save() method in JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a 50k records in the table, I fetched all(50k) records using JPA findAll() method and using for loop update one filed of all record and then after performing an update all records using save() method by passing the object list. but I'm getting an error like

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not load an entity: nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity:
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Comment: Why do you read all the 50 records at once? Can't you create a update query for that?

Comment: Can you please share your method and repository class?

Comment: Don't... Create a method that returns a `Stream` to load elements one-by-one and process them. Currently you are loosing way too much time either loading or writing the data. I strongly suggest a read-up on how to do batch processing with Hibernate/JPA.